# Show each if value is 0 show once if year is set PHP Calendar

Tags: php, calendar

I have made an event calandar and i give my users an option when they add an event to: Show each year? With and checkbox.

So if checkbox is checked I insert an 0 as year in my database if the checkbox is not checked I insert the actual date in the database.

http://i44.tinypic.com/2cdd1zm.png

But how can i show it on my calander each year if the value of year = 0;

BTW jaar = year.

```
//for showing once
if (Syear != 0){

$sqlEvent = "SELECT titel,content FROM **** WHERE `maand` = '$month' AND `dag` = '$day' AND '$year' = `jaar`";

$resultEvents = mysql_query($sqlEvent);
}
//for showing every year
else
{
$sqlEvent = "SELECT titel,content FROM *** WHERE `maand` = '$month' AND `dag` = '$day'";
$resultEvents = mysql_query($sqlEvent);
}
echo "<hr>";
// show event
while ($events = mysql_fetch_array($resultEvents)){
echo "Title: ".$events['titel']."<br>";
echo "Detail: ".$events['content']."<br>";
echo $year;
}
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to pull the years back from your database in addition to the title and content.  So if you change both of the queries to do something like `SELECT titel,content,jaar` then each retrieved row will also include the year.

Then you can change `echo $year` to `echo $events['jaar']`.